# Shisha Vachamishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred fifty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting and relevant answers.*
- *Accept the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*It's been a while since our last power of two, and it'll be a longer while until the next one ...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

אהרן = 256

256 = דברים

Moshe told Hashem לא איש **דברים** אנכי

Hashem responded ויאמר הלא אהרן אחיך הלוי ידעתי כי דבר ידבר Aharon will be the איש דברים

Comment: Cute! Your own discovery?

Comment: Never saw it anywhere.